# How to change position of md-grid-list child position ( md-grid-tile ) from left to right?

Tags: material-design, angular-material

I have  `md-grid-list`  in my code and it has three `md-grid-tile` as children,   `md-grid-list` has relative position and  `md-grid-tile`s have absolute position with left attribute that calculated automatically. How can I change this position to right and puts `md-grid-tile`s from right to left instead of left to right ?

Answer (score 0):

Whats about `document.body.dir == 'rtl';`?
I don't know any angular-material but I think that's what you need.

Maybe this Plunker would help you - [click me](http://plnkr.co/edit/bo2OHvlK4jlrpZPWAJv6?p=preview)

or have a look into this github [angular.js "ng-grid" rtl](https://gist.github.com/nissoh/8612979)

Comment: I want to do this with css not javascript